# Create database from a template by a script

Tags: sql-server, database, templates

I'm running a robot test on one of our test environments, and every night, before the test runs, I would like to dump the database, and create it again from a template.

I know that PSQL has a solution for it:

```
CREATE DATABASE name
    [ TEMPLATE [=] template ]
```

Is there a way I can do this in SQL Server, and write a script for it?

Comment: A new database is based on the `model` database on the Server. As this is a test environment, perhaps you need to change the definition of the `model` database, and then all future databases on that instance will have all the properties you have set there?

Comment: Perhaps [dbcc clonedatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Or just restore a backup

Answer (score 0):

You can write any kind of functionality as text and then execute it as a variable. That way you can store your template as text, where you would define the database.

```
declare @example nvarchar(max) 
set @example = 'create database examplebase'

exec sp_executesql @example
```

You can use this in a stored procedure where you can set database name ect. as a parameter.

```
create PROCEDURE sp_recreateDB
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @databasename nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    declare @example nvarchar(max) 
    SET @example = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@Databasename) + N';'
    -- ect...
    exec sp_executesql @example
END
GO
```

Comment: This is very very open to injection; you need to properly quote your objects. What do you think would happen here if someone ran `EXEC createDatabase 't; CREATE LOGIN NL WITH PASSWORD = '123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;'; EXEC createDatabase 'd; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER NL;';`?

Comment: @Larnu Fair enough. He can, however, store it in a query file that he then just runs without any kind of injection risk.

Comment: Why not just properly quote using `QUOTENAME`? A file could pose as much a risk, as someone could edit the file.

Comment: It would be `SET @Example = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME @Databasename) + N';'` [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)